# How to reference node_modules in Angular 2 using this folder structure?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm getting started with Angular 2 and I'm trying to use the following folder structure:

```
- angular-app
    - src 
    - dist
    - package.json
```

Where `src` is where the actual source goes and `dist` is where the production version goes after typescript compilation and so forth.

Now, to run the app, I've used the quickstart suggestion, I've installed `lite-server` and I have the `scripts` section of `package.json` defined as:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "tsc && concurrently \"npm run tsc:w\" \"npm run lite\" ",
    "lite": "lite-server",
    "postinstall": "typings install",
    "tsc": "tsc",
    "tsc:w": "tsc -w",
    "typings": "typings"
}
```

Now, to tell `lite-server` that the code is inside `src` I've added one folder `configs` to the root, with one `bs-config.json` file with contents:

```
{
    "port": 3000,
    "files": ["./src/**/*.{html,htm,css,js}"],
    "server": { "baseDir": "./src/" }
}
```

and changed the `lite` script to be `lite-server -c configs/bs-config.json`.

Now, it does serve the files from within `src`. It locates everything inside there. But there's an issue.

On the `index.html` there are several scripts loading from `../node_modules`. And `lite-server` is unaware of this folder, so that it returns 404 for any request going into `../node_modules`.

This is a big problem. How do I solve it? How do I request the scripts inside `../node_modules` from within `src` and get them served by lite-server?

Answer (score 1):

You can try to add your angular-app folder as root to the bs-config.json file (note the additional "." in the baseDir):

```
  "server": { 
    "baseDir": ["./src", "."]
  }
```

a reference like the following example in angular-app/src/index.html:

```
<script src="node_modules/core-js/client/shim.min.js"></script>
```

would then be resolved (assuming your nodes_modules has your 'angular-app' as its parent folder).